# Does related localization give more accuracy?

Tags: gps, position

Let's suppose that we use another device as an RTK base. Both base and rover are moving and communicate constantly (via 5G for instance). Besides they get common GPS error from the satellite on the same area. Will this set give an ability to localize them more precisely one from another (than traditional GPS gives) or not?